# The Arrays.fill() method causes an exception

Tags: java

Right now I am having trouble filling an array with spaces. Whenever I use the array fill method I keep getting an exception. Right now I excluded the rest of the code and only included the ones that causes problems. Here it is. Note I am a beginner to java so don't get angry if this is too simple of a question. I have searched here and could not find anything.

```
public class board 
{       
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        char board [][] = new char  [6][7]; 
        int column=0; 
        int row=0;

        java.util.Arrays.fill(board,' ');
    }
}
```

The exception says

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException:
>    java.lang.Character
>    at java.util.Arrays.fill(Arrays.java:2710)
>    at java.util.Arrays.fill(Arrays.java:2685)
>    at board.main(board.java:26)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Arrays.fill` expects a single-dimensional array, you're passing in a jagged array.

Instead, do this:

```
for(int x=0;x<board.length;x++)
    for(int y=0;y<board[x].length;y++)
        board[x][y] = ' ';
```

or this:

```
for(int x=0;x<board.length;x++)
    Arrays.fill( board[x], ' ' );
```

Comment: It probably compiles because the compiler interprets it as a call to `fill(Object[] a, Object val)`

Comment: Better still `for (char[] row : board) { java.util.Arrays.fill(row, ' ');}`

Answer (score 2):

**FROM JAVA API 
ArrayStoreException:**
Thrown to indicate that an attempt has been made to store the wrong type of object into an array.

```
Arrays.fill();
```

method takes a single dimentional array as a parameter, you are passing a 2-d array thus the exception

Comment: So whats the point of the fill method if it only works on single dimentional arrays?